# What is "Mars-Tech" and why does Ubuntu think it's my video driver?

Tags: ati, video, radeon

One for the weird file: I've upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04, and (1) it now thinks my video driver is from "Mars-Tech Corporation", and (2) it is sizing my screen such that everything exceeds the boundaries of the screen by about 100px. I can't QUITE see the top, bottom, or sides of the screen, at any size that I resize it to.

I've downloaded and installed the latest AMD drivers for my video card (Radeon 5450). Why does Ubuntu now think "Mars-Tech" rules my roost?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot in your question of where exactly you're seeing this "Mars-Tech Corporation" appear on your system, please?

Answer (score 1):

Mars-tech Corp. is an indian manufacturer of monitors / tv-sets. Your monitor/tv may have another label but infact it is a Mars-tech device, and like many of these companies do, so they too are still using Overscan without any need.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overscan

If you're using a HDMI connection it may be helpful to use the ordinary xserver-xorg-video-ati driver instead of the special one. You will have no sound via HDMI then but proper screen fit and picture quality. Your monitor will detect the signal through HDMI as VDI...

But before deinstalling your actual driver ask some clever freak! I am not shure what will happen...